# how to calculate the similarity between two items in this case

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an item `A` (Symphony Impromptu No. 1 for Frederic Chopin) and i want to know if it is more similar to another item `B` (Symphony Polonaise Heroique for Frederic Chopin) or an item `C` (Symphony 5th for Beethoven)

I have some measures, which are:

> measure 1: has the same artist.
>
> measure 2: has the same music key.
>
> measure 3: has the same music era.

The context is: after making some measures, I got :

1. According to measure 1: item A and item B are 0.4 similar (0.4 means 40% similar)
2. According to measure 2: item A and item B are 0.6 similar
3. According to measure 3: item A and item B are 0.1 similar
4. According to measure 2: item A and item C are 0.6 similar

However the measures don't account the same for the similarity, because `measure 1` and `measure 2` is **4** time important than measure 3.

I want to know if the item `A` is more close to the item `B` or to the item `C`

#### What I was thinking of

I should multiply the measure's value by the measure's weight. Thus:

1. According to measure 1: item A and item B are 1.6 (0.4 * 4) similar  (160% similar !)
2. According to measure 2: item A and item B are 2.4 (0.6 * 4) similar
3. According to measure 3: item A and item B are 0.1 (0.1 * 1) similar
4. According to measure 2: item A and item C are 2.4 (0.6 * 4) similar

Then I need to make the average of the similarities for each item. **I don't know if this is correct way of not, and even if correct i don't know if the approach that I'm using to make the average is correct** So:

The similarity between A and B is : `(1.6 + 2.4 + 0.1)/3` = 1.36

The similarity between A and C is: 2.4/1 = 2.4

Then I have to make normalisation for both similarities as the following:
1.36 + 2.4 = 3.76.

So the similarity between A and B is : 1.36/3.76 = 36%
the similarity between A and C is: 2.4/3.76 = 63%

I really doubt that what I've made is correct because look at the numbers, they say that the similarity between A and C is way much more than A and B, though A and B has more measures (3 measures could be applied between them), while A and C could be applied for just one measure

What's wrong did I do? is it that when I make the similarity between A and C, I should've make this:

The similarity between A and C is: 2.4 + 0 + 0 /3 = 0.8

instead of this:

The similarity between A and C is: 2.4/1 = 2.4

?

or it is something else? or **is the whole way wrong**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to

> figure out a measure to compare musical works that incorporates the measures numbered $1,2,3$ in which weights of measures $1,2$ are $4$ times greater than that of measure $3$.

Suppose $a,b$ are two musical works and $g_j$ denote the measure $j$. Let the measure to be found be $g$. If the contribution of $g_1,g_2,g_3$ to $g$ is in the proportion $4:4:1$, $g$ can be found as
$$
g(a,b)={4\over4+4+1}g_1(a,b)+{4\over4+4+1}g_2(a,b)+{1\over4+4+1}g_3(a,b)
$$
If the contribution of $g_1+g_2,g_3$ to $g$ is in the proportion $4:1$, $g$ can be found as
$$
g(a,b)={4\over4+1}(g_1(a,b)+g_2(a,b))+{1\over4+1}g_3(a,b)
$$
Assuming you know $g_j(a,b)$ for all possible values of $j,a,b$ (e.g $g_1(A,B)=0.4$) you just have to compare $g(A,B)$ and $g(A,C)$. If $g(A,B)>g(A,C)$, $A$ is closer to $B$ than $C$ and vice versa.

I think the Wikipedia article on [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) would help you.

Comment: the weight of g1 is 4 times than g3, and the weight of g2 is 4 times than g3. I'm trying to make calculating for your solution. wait please

Comment: Note that the first combination also assumes that the weights of $g_1,g_2$ are equal. Is this what you want? Otherwise you have to specify the ratio of their weights.

Comment: according to your solution, the similarity between A and B is: 0.4 (4/9) + 0.6 (4/9) + 0.1 (1/9) = 0.44, while the similarity between A and C is: 0.6 (4/9) + 0 (4/9) + 0 (1/9) = 2.6. Then 0.44 > 0.26, then B is closer than C according to A. right please ?

Comment: nothing of the weights g1, g2, .....gn is equal, (they could be but not necessary) , will than change your answer please ?

Comment: so you're saying that your answer is not correct now? i see it is logical, right?

Comment: being from the same artist is not a good measure at all, there are many musical features that contributes better to the similarity. for example, the type, the note, the harmony ....

Comment: okay thank you very much, you're a matchmetical genius, can I ask another separated question and tell u?

Comment: If you want $g_2$ to have more weight then just let the ratio of $g_1,g_2$ be $1:70$ or whatever you like. Yes you may ask another question.....

Comment: kindly is the result always between 0 and 1 ? or it could be great than 1 ?

Comment: It's always between $0$ and $1$ :) if $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I love you .... :)